# Dart class using io or http

Tags: import, dart

I would like to create a class hierarchy dealing with `Sockets`. I have 2 classes, for the sake of being generic, let's call them `A` and `B`. `A` is the superclass which `B` extends from.

Here's an example using `dart:io`:

```dart
// a.dart
import "dart:async";
import "dart:io";

class A {
  Future<String> socketStuff(String cmd) {
    Completer com = new Completer();
    Socket.connect("localhost", 5555).then((socket) {
      socket.write(cmd);
      socket.listen((data) {
        String dataStr = new String.fromCharCodes(data);
        com.complete(dataStr);
      });
    });
    return com.future;
  }
}
```

```dart
//b.dart
import "a.dart";

class B extends A {      
  Future<String> doStuff() {
    // Calls a method that does stuff with sockets, but doesn't really know
    // it.
    return socketStuff("doStuff");
  }

  Future<String> moreStuff() {
    // Another method like the above one.
    return socketStuff("moreStuff");
  }
}
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to use it on both a command line application and a web application. class `A` requires that I use either the `dart:io` library or the `dart:http` library.

I've came up with a couple of ways to work around this, but it can add a decent amount of complications. Hopefully this will be clear...

- Create an interface called `I`. Have `A` and a new class, `A2`, implement `I`. `A` will be used for command line applications and `A2` will be used for web applications. The issue is that it makes it slightly more complicated to create an object of class `B`, because `B` will have to take either an `A` or an `A2` in it's constructor.
- Create an interface called `I`. Have an abstract class `A` which has a list of all the shared methods, and implements `I`, without actually implementing anything. Then have two classes called `B` and `B2` (one for command line and one for web) extend `A` and implement the missing methods from `I`. This option is pretty much reversing what I already have, with an interface brought in.

I think the second option is the better one, but does anyone else have other thoughts on a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I would actually suggest a 3rd solution (and other solutions are possible). It sounds like your B class will be a helper class that will manage all the logic, so it should contain a "I" member that could be instantiated with either A1 from io and A2 from console.

Here is a concrete example where A is here a simple HttpFetcher interface to get a string from a url

```dart
// ihttp.dart
library ihttp;

import 'dart:async';

abstract class IHttpFetcher {
  Future<String> getString(String uri);
}
```

A browser implementation

```dart
// http_browser.dart
library http_browser;

import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
import 'ihttp.dart';

class HttpBrowser implements IHttpFetcher {
  @override
  Future<String> getString(String uri) {
    return HttpRequest.getString(uri);
 }
}
```

A console implementation (not sure I handle errors correctly here)

```dart
// browser_console.dart
library http_console;

import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'ihttp.dart';

class HttpConsole implements IHttpFetcher {
  HttpClient client =  new HttpClient();

  @override
  Future<String> getString(String uri) {
    var completer = new Completer<String>();
    client.getUrl(Uri.parse(uri))
     .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
     .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
       StringBuffer body = new StringBuffer();
       response.listen(
        (data) => body.write(new String.fromCharCodes(data)),
        onDone: () => completer.complete(body.toString()),
        onError: (e) => completer.completeError(e));
    })
    .catchError((e) {
      completer.completeError(e);
    });

    return completer.future;
  }
}
```

The "B" class you provider won't depend on either io or browser (and it cannot depend on both) and provider helper functions

```dart
// B.dart
library B;

import 'dart:async';
import 'ihttp.dart';

class B {
  IHttpFetcher fetcher;
  B(this.fetcher);
  Future<String> getGoogleCom() => fetcher.getString("http://www.google.com");
  Future<String> getHtml5Rocks() => fetcher.getString("http://updates.html5rocks.com");
}
```

And you will take care in the main of the console app to instantiate B as needed

```dart
// console version
import 'http_console.dart';
import 'B.dart';

B b = new B(new HttpConsole());
```

or

```dart
// Browser version
import 'http_browser.dart';
import 'B.dart';

B b = new B(new HttpBrowser());
```

And in you shared source code you can call B helpers

```dart
b.getGoogleCom().then((String content) {
  print(content);
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is the solution that I tried to explain first. You obviously described it much better though. Thanks. The only part that I don't like about it is that the user of Main has to pass in an object in the constructor.